# Kubernetes File Service Not Persist Files

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, digital-ocean, persistent-volumes, fileserver

I want to run kubernetes file server but files are deleted. I also tried Digitaloceon and GKE and got the same result.

Everything works fine until the pod is deleted, but when the pod is deleted it returns to the starting position on the public path.

I spent a few days with this please help. :)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: file-claim
  namespace: u-e
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: "do-block-storage-retain"
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fileapp
  namespace: u-e
  labels:
    app: file
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: file
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: file
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fileapp
          image: ghcr.io/myvarlik/file
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8888
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/public"
              name: filevolume
      volumes:
        - name: filevolume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: file-claim
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: gh-regcred
```

```
allowVolumeExpansion: true
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-23T06:31:00Z"
  labels:
    c3.doks.digitalocean.com/component: csi-controller-service
    c3.doks.digitalocean.com/plane: data
    doks.digitalocean.com/managed: "true"
  name: do-block-storage-retain
  resourceVersion: "8814934"
  uid: f711cf4d-efe9-4c63-bd6f-476b684818a8
provisioner: dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
reclaimPolicy: Retain
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  annotations:
    pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
    volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-name: ""
    volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-namespace: ""
  creationTimestamp: "2022-11-13T09:41:49Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  - external-attacher/dobs-csi-digitalocean-com
  name: pvc-74053a19-97cf-49e3-bdcc-7481c57c82b2
  resourceVersion: "17951524"
  uid: 8a0bb8df-6801-4c44-ab5f-7f065ed22037
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: file-claim
    namespace: u-e
    resourceVersion: "17950915"
    uid: 74053a19-97cf-49e3-bdcc-7481c57c82b2
  csi:
    driver: dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
    fsType: ext4
    volumeAttributes:
      storage.kubernetes.io/csiProvisionerIdentity: 1663943304029-8081-dobs.csi.digitalocean.com
    volumeHandle: 651836fc-6337-11ed-8354-0a58ac14d348
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: do-block-storage-retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Bound
```

I wanted to publish a file server in Kubernet, but the files are not persistent. It goes away when the pod is refreshed or deleted.

Comment: Can you show us the defintion of your `StorageClass` and your `PersistentVolume`?

Comment: @DawidKruk thans for comment. I'm adding to the topic.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see what cause have caused that. Maybe how the `dobs.csi.digitalocean.com` is working under the hood is causing that? Have you tried to ask on digital ocean's forum by any chance?